# Open port 80 on Linksys WRT160NL?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I have tried to open port 80 on my computer.
Things I've tried:

- Putting the http server WAMP, online (so it servers all connections, not only the ones from own machine)
- Open port 80 in Windows's firewall.
- 80 port forward on the router.
- Put the router's management interface on https only in order to free http (port 80).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- **Disable Upnp on the router. Upnp reserves port 80 (but the port is seen as Closed) and port forwarding will not work.** Administration/Management/Upnp/Disabled

  *- and then -*
- Put http server online (so it serves all connections, including from outside it's own network)
- Open operating system's firewall.
- Port forward port 80 on the router.

The first one is not mentioned anywhere and it's not obvious in any way.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer!